# Geostatistical layer extrapolation in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

Just recently switched to using ArcGIS Pro from ArcMap 10.6
Does anyone know how to change the extent of a geostatistical layer in Pro?

In ArcMap this is a simple task ([as outlined here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/geostatistical-analyst/changing-the-extent-of-a-geostatistical-layer.htm#)) however this option does not appear in the layer properties in Pro.

Comment: If you want to answer your own Question, please use an Answer, not a link-only comment.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this functionality was removed in ArcGIS Pro.

Explanation and solution is outlined here:

https://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDEwOTM5Mw==